# SQL Server Ignore row if duplicate exists unless id exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I ran the follow SQL Query and got the following rows as an output:

```
SELECT EventTime
      ,UserID
      ,SubAddr
FROM tablename
WHERE EventType = 20 AND 
    (SubAddr = 1 OR SubAddr = 2)
```

```
 EventTime  UserID  SubAddr 

2018-05-04 16:47:56.000 113 1    
2018-05-04 16:48:45.000 113 2    
2018-05-04 16:49:17.000 113 1    
2018-05-04 16:49:27.000 113 2    
2018-05-04 16:49:48.000 113 1    
2018-05-04 16:49:57.000 113 2    
2018-05-04 16:50:15.000 113 1    
2018-05-04 16:51:01.000 113 2    
2018-05-04 16:51:23.000 113 1    
2018-05-04 16:51:33.000 113 2    
2018-05-07 15:42:13.000 114 1    
2018-05-07 15:42:16.000 114 1    
2018-05-07 15:42:26.000 114 1    
2018-05-07 15:42:35.000 114 2    
2018-05-07 15:42:43.000 114 2    
2018-05-07 15:42:54.000 114 1    
2018-05-07 15:43:02.000 114 1    
2018-05-07 15:43:11.000 114 2    
2018-05-07 15:43:20.000 114 2    
2018-05-07 15:43:35.000 114 1    
2018-05-07 15:43:42.000 114 1    
2018-05-07 15:43:51.000 114 2    
2018-05-07 15:43:58.000 114 2
```

I want to change the query in such a way that it only gets the rows where it get the first eventtime for every user for both subaddr 1 and 2. If there is another row where subaddr is 1 after a row where is the same userID and subaddr = 2 I want it to retrieve that row too.

See the following example

```
 EventTime  UserID  SubAddr 

2018-05-07 15:42:13.000 114 1  <- This row    
2018-05-07 15:42:16.000 114 1  <- Not this row    
2018-05-07 15:42:26.000 114 1  <- Not this row    
2018-05-07 15:42:35.000 114 2  <- This row    
2018-05-07 15:42:43.000 114 2  <- Not this row    
2018-05-07 15:42:54.000 114 1  <- This row    
2018-05-07 15:43:02.000 114 1  <- Not this row    
2018-05-07 15:43:11.000 114 2  <- This row    
2018-05-07 15:43:20.000 114 2  <- Not this row    
2018-05-07 15:43:35.000 114 1  <- This row    
2018-05-07 15:43:42.000 114 1  <- Not this row    
2018-05-07 15:43:51.000 114 2  <- This row    
2018-05-07 15:43:58.000 114 2  <- Not this row
```

I hope this example make it clearer. I have been struggling with this all day and haven't been able to find an answer

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Do you have window functions available?

Comment: If you can use window functions you could create a CTE adding a column with ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY EventTime) and then self join to compare successive record relationships. You could also do something using LAG and LEAD as well, but I don't have test data and someone else will probably provide this answer in a minute or two. :p

Answer (score 0):

Lee Mac solution don't working for me, because you will take in this table just

```
2018-05-07 15:42:13.000 114 1  <- This row    

2018-05-07 15:42:35.000 114 2  <- This row
```

Because you selecting a min from grouping operator of user and subAddr.

I have simple solution (but you must check for you data integrity if working) 
cut the data in this way:

```
2018-05-07 15:42
```

and Use this query

```
SELECT distinct(EventTime, UserID, SubAddr)
FROM tablename 
WHERE EventType = 20 AND (SubAddr = 1 OR SubAddr = 2)
```

in this way you will take this data:

```
2018-05-07 15:42:13.000 114 1  <- This row    

2018-05-07 15:42:35.000 114 2  <- This row    

2018-05-07 15:42:54.000 114 1  <- This row    
2018-05-07 15:43:02.000 114 1  <- Not this row (this will capture) 

2018-05-07 15:43:11.000 114 2  <- This row   

2018-05-07 15:43:35.000 114 1  <- This row    


2018-05-07 15:43:51.000 114 2  <- This row
```

This is fast way, otherwise you need make a nested query, that will be more complex.

But i repeat, this is not solution to your problem, just a short way.

Comment: I don't think this will work; it doesn't take the logical ordering into consideration being requested. I don't see any duplicated EventTime values in the sample output.

Comment: You are right @EricJ.Price i edit the answer. I thinking to distinct attribute. But otherwhise have the same issues from previous post.

Comment: The SQL Server doesn' t accept multiple columns in DISTINCT

Answer (score 0):

Use `lag()`

```
with t as (
      select t.*, lag(subaddr) over (partition by userid order by eventtime) as prev_subaddr
      from tablename t
      where EventType = 20 and SubAddr in (1, 2)
    )
select EventTime, UserID, SubAddr
from t
where prev_subaddr is null or prev_subaddr <> subaddr;
```

EDIT:

If you don't have `lag()`, you can use `apply`:

```
with t as (
      select t.*, tprev.subaddr as prev_subaddr
      from tablename t outer apply
           (select top (1) t2.*
            from tablename t2
            where t2.userid = t.userid and
                  t2.EventType = 20 and
                  t2.SubAddr in (1, 2) and
                  t2.eventtime < t.eventtime
            order by eventtime desc
           ) tprev
      where EventType = 20 and SubAddr in (1, 2)
    )
select EventTime, UserID, SubAddr
from t
where prev_subaddr is null or prev_subaddr <> subaddr;
```

Comment: lag isn't recognized by SQL server

Comment: @Laurens . . . `lag()` has been in SQL Server for six years.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017.

Comment: i'm working on SQL Server 2008. At this moment there is no way for me to upgrade.

Comment: I get the following error after your edit: Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: After removing the line that is causing the error I get an output. It gets the first and second row right. but after that it gets every row the same and has dulplicates of every row

Comment: EventTime UserID SubAddr

2018-11-06 15:45:35.000 113 1

2018-11-06 15:46:25.000 113 2

2018-11-06 15:46:25.000 113 2

2018-11-06 15:46:25.000 113 2

2018-11-06 15:46:25.000 113 2

2018-11-06 15:46:25.000 113 2

2018-11-06 15:46:26.000 113 2

2018-11-06 15:46:26.000 113 2

2018-11-06 15:46:26.000 113 2
2018-11-06 15:46:26.000 113 2
2018-11-06 15:46:26.000 113 2
2018-11-06 15:46:30.000 113 2
2018-11-06 15:46:30.000 113 2
2018-11-06 15:46:30.000 113 2
2018-11-06 15:46:30.000 113 2
2018-11-06 15:46:30.000 113 2

Comment: @Laurens . . . It was missing the `top (1)`.